# How to convert combination of text values into date datatype of database in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have made a registration page in which there was combination of a drop down and two textboxes to select date of birth

- drop-down for month
- textbox for day and
- one more textbox for year

(I can't upload image due to less than 10 reputations)

I want to store that combination of inputs into database.
Is it possible to do such ?
If yes,  please suggest the best way to do it.

**Registration.aspx.cs** code is following

I have tried convert function but it is giving an error, so please suggest the correction. and if possible explain the concept behind date datatype of sql-server

Thank You.

```
public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd,cmd1;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    protected void Register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       con.Open();
       con1.Open();
       cmd = new SqlCommand("select username from registration where username=@user", con);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user",username.Text);
       dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
       if (dr.Read())
       {
        usernamefailure.Text = "Username not available";
       }

       else
       {
           dr.Close();
           cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into Registration(FirstName,LastName,UserName,Password,Birthday,gender,phone,termsofservice)values('@firstname','@lastname','@username','@password','@birthday','@gender','@phone','@termsofservice')", con);
           cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstname.Text);
           cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastname.Text);
           cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text);
           cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.Text);
        //   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthday", Convert.ToDateTime(month.SelectedValue + day.Text + "," + year.Text));
           cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender.SelectedValue);
           cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", Code.Text + phone.Text);
           cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@termsofservice", termsofservice.Checked.ToString());
           int a = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
           if (a > 0)
           {
               Session["s"] = username.Text;
               Response.Write("You are registered --- Welcome to our Service");
           }
           else
           {
               Response.Write("Server Error -- Try after some time");
           }
       }
       con.Close();
       con1.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: You are asking how to combine text of month, day, and year into a single variable to be stored in SQL date, correct? Do you really need such a large wall of code to express your question?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

`cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthday", new DateTime(int.Parse(year.Text),int.Parse(month.SelectedValue.ToString()),int.Parse(day.Text));`

be sure the textbox has a valid string number.